# How to Add vertical line in table Latex

Tags: latex, tabular, multirow

I have this sheet of latex code.

```
\begin{table}[c]

\caption{\textbf{the results of analysis of variance (One Way ANOVA) 
  for the differences in the responses of the study sample according
  to different classes.}}
\bigskip
\centering

\begin{tabular}  {|M{4.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.75cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{2.5cm}|}
\hline
 \textbf{} & \textbf{Variance}         
 &\textbf{Sum of the squares }  & \textbf{Degrees of Freedom } &
 \textbf{Average Squares} &\textbf{P Value} &\textbf{Statistical  significance } \\ 
\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{Q11.2}} & UK &122 & 0.14 & 0.348 &
\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{0.978}  }  &  \multirow{3}{*}
{\makecell{0.329}}\\  \cline{2-5}
             & SA  & 224 & 0.10 & 0.304
             \\  \cline{2-5}
             & SA  & 224 & 0.10 & 0.304
             &&    \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I get this output[image] :

I don't know how to  fill empty vertical lines!

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `\multirow`, you have to include empty cells in each row that you want the multirow to span. 
This means that the line

```
    & SA  & 224 & 0.10 & 0.304 \\
```

actually should read as

```
    & SA  & 224 & 0.10 & 0.304 & & \\
```

This should give the desired result!

Two additional remarks:

- You might want to reconsider the usage of the `\makecell`-command, which is in my opinion not necessary.
- It was not easy to answer your question as you did not provide the following defintion, which you have probably used: `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`

Here is the entire code i used

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={160mm,255mm},centering,headsep=5mm,footskip=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[c]

\caption{\textbf{the results of analysis of variance (One Way ANOVA) 
  for the differences in the responses of the study sample according
  to different classes.}}
\bigskip
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|M{4.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.75cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{2.5cm}|}
\hline
    & \textbf{Variance} & \textbf{Sum of the squares} & 
        \textbf{Degrees of Freedom } & \textbf{Average Squares} &
        \textbf{P Value} & \textbf{Statistical  significance } \\ 
\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{Q11.2} & UK &122 & 0.14 & 0.348 & 
        \multirow{3}{*}{0.978} & \multirow{3}{*}{0.329}\\  
\cline{2-5}
             & SA  & 224 & 0.10 & 0.304 & & \\
\cline{2-5}
             & SA  & 224 & 0.10 & 0.304 & & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

to generate this output
[image]